Decrease in built-up area of Telangana, India obtained from Bhuvan API LULC 250k data in 2015-16 and 2017-18
I'm conducting statistical analyses of built-up areas across several villages in Telangana, India using LULC 250k AOI-wise data from the Bhuvan API.
While analyzing data from 2015-16 and 2017-18, I observed a decrease in built-up area in many regions, which seems counterintuitive. Typically, built-up areas, defined as land with construction, should either increase or remain stable over time.
Image of graph showing the same:

Question:
What could be the reason for this decline in built-up area, and is this expected behavior for this dataset?
I have obtained the geometries of the villages from Shrid Polygons data available at SHRUG by Development Data Lab
Here’s an example API request I’m using to retrieve the data (Template can be found at Bhuvan API website > Thematic statistics > LULC 250k AOI Wise)
(Access token can be retrieved from Bhuvan API website > Access Token > Select theme "LULC AOI Wise"):
import requests
import json
import re
from shapely import wkt
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import logging
import time

# Configure logging
log_file = 'lulc_processing.log'
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, filename=log_file, filemode='a', format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

polygon = None  # Initialize polygon variable
tolerance = 0.000015  # Set tolerance for polygon simplification


def extract_json_from_html(html_text):
    """Extract JSON data from HTML using regular expressions."""
    json_pattern = re.compile(r'(\[.*\])', re.DOTALL)
    match = json_pattern.search(html_text)
    if match:
        json_str = match.group(1)
        try:
            return json.loads(json_str)
        except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
            logging.error(f"JSON decode error: {e}")
            print(f"JSON decode error: {e}")
            return None
    else:
        logging.error("No JSON data found in HTML")
        print("No JSON data found in HTML")
        return None


def get_lulc_data(year, polygon, token, option='json'):
    """Fetch LULC data for a given polygon."""
    base_url = "https://bhuvan-app1.nrsc.gov.in/api/lulc250k/curl_lulc250k.php"
    params = {
        "polygon": polygon,
        "year": year,
        "option": option,
        "token": token
    }

    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    response = requests.post(base_url, headers=headers, params=params, timeout=30)
    logging.info(f"Response status code: {response.status_code}")
    print(f"Response status code: {response.status_code}")

    try:
        response.raise_for_status()
        if 'application/json' in response.headers.get('Content-Type', ''):
            return response.json()
        else:
            logging.warning("Received non-JSON response")
            print("Received non-JSON response")
            json_data = extract_json_from_html(response.text)
            logging.info(f"Extracted json from response: {response.text}")
            print(f"Extracted json from response: {response.text}")
            if json_data:
                return json_data
            else:
                logging.error("Failed to extract JSON from HTML response")
                print("Failed to extract JSON from HTML response")
                return None
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
        logging.error(f"HTTP error occurred: {err}")
        print(f"HTTP error occurred: {err}")
        if response.status_code == 414:  # Handle HTTP 414 error (Request URI too long)
            polygon = polygon.simplify(tolerance=tolerance)  # Simplify the polygon
            logging.info("Simplified polygon due to HTTP 414 error")
            print(f"Simplified polygon with tolerance {str(tolerance)} due to HTTP 414 error")
        raise
    except ValueError as json_err:
        logging.error(f"JSON decode error: {json_err}")
        logging.error(f"Response text: {response.text}")
        print(f"JSON decode error: {json_err}")
        print(f"Response text: {response.text}")
        raise


def process_lulc_data(lulc_data):
    """Process LULC data and categorize areas by year and land use."""
    data_by_year = {}

    for record in lulc_data:
        year = record.get("Year", "")
        desc = record.get("LULC Description", "").strip() 
        # Remove extra spaces
        area = float(record.get("Area in Sq. Km", 0))  # Ensure area is a float
        if desc != 'Built-up':
            continue
        if year not in data_by_year:
            data_by_year[year] = {}  # Create a new dictionary for the year

        if desc in data_by_year[year]:
            data_by_year[year][desc] += area  # Add to the existing area
        else:
            data_by_year[year][desc] = area  # Initialize the area for this description

    return data_by_year


# Example usage
polygon_wkt = "POLYGON ((78.38246377200005 19.861716572000034, 78.38200866600005 19.870488317000024, 78.38230791500007 19.877670315000046, 78.37761966700003 19.88036356400005, 78.36654742000007 19.879964565000023, 78.35958346600006 19.882857314000034, 78.35772748600004 19.874373519000073, 78.35867927100009 19.864879469000073, 78.36305038900008 19.865230004000068, 78.37797491800006 19.861941819000037, 78.38246377200005 19.861716572000034))"  # Example polygon WKT

polygon = wkt.loads(polygon_wkt)

year = '2014_15,2015_16'  # Specify the year
token = "xxxxxx"  # Replace with your token
max_retries = 5
retry_delay = 5

# Retry mechanism
retries = 0
lulc_data = None
while retries < max_retries:
    try:
        lulc_data = get_lulc_data(year, polygon, token)
        if lulc_data:
            break
        else:
            logging.warning(f"No LULC data returned, retrying... ({retries + 1}/{max_retries})")
            print(f"No LULC data returned, retrying... ({retries + 1}/{max_retries})")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.warning(f"Error fetching LULC data: {e}")
        print(f"Error fetching LULC data: {e}")
    retries += 1
    time.sleep(retry_delay)

# Process the LULC data
if lulc_data:
    processed_data = process_lulc_data(lulc_data)
    print("Processed LULC Data:", processed_data)
else:
    print("Failed to retrieve LULC data after multiple retries.")


These are the values I get:
Processed LULC Data: {'2014_15': {'Built-up': 0.06}, '2015_16': {'Built-up': 0.05}}

Note: Documentation for the Bhuvan API was not readily available.

Have you looked at your data for omissions or void areas for the datasets in question? Perhaps try erase the previous year and see what is left.

There was Monsoon Flooding in Southern India in 2015 that may of impacted buildings and built-up areas https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015_South_India_floods

@Mapperz Thank you for your reply, I am however only considering regions within Telangana and not Andhra Pradesh. These regions are not near the coast and were not affected by the floods. Could you please suggest any other reason for this fall?

@MichaelStimson Thank you for your reply. I have cleaned the data and the panel doesn't contain any regions with missing values in any of the years. Is this what you were referring to? Could you please elaborate?
